# How to create different dataset based on the distint levels of an variable in R?

Tags: r

I have 7 variables in the datasets .out of which one variable has 5 levels ,I need create 5 datasets for the same.

Comment: Please consider to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s in a `list`.  If the variable name of the column with 5 levels is 'Col', use that to `split` the dataset

```
lst <- split(data, data$Col)
```

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.

Comment: @PraveenChougale  Assuming that you have a column with 5 unique values, it would split as intended

Comment: It I need to store the datasets ,its not possible

Comment: @PraveenChougale  You can do all the manipulations within the `list`.  If you need to save it, `lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.csv(lst[[x]], paste0(x, ".csv")))`